# Android ListView with button

Tags: java, android, listview, button

So i am making this app where i will have a list of items that contains text and a button besides it.

I am getting this error in my Custom Adapter class:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

The entire Custom Adapter class is as follows:

```
package com.android.ict.seneca.androidpocketguide;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;


public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

    private Context context;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context,
                             int resourceId,
                             List<RowItem> items ) {

        super( context, resourceId, items );
        this.context = context;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtDate;
        TextView txtLocation;
        Button button;

    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater =
                (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
                        Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.nam );
            holder.txtDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.dat );
            holder.txtLocation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.loc );
            holder.button = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.txtName.setText( rowItem.getNameId() );
        holder.txtDate.setText( rowItem.getLocation() );
        holder.txtLocation.setText( rowItem.getDate() );

        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Delete button pressed: ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Your code that you want to execute on this button click
            }

        });

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

I have 2 layouts, 1 for the listview itelf and then another one for just the buttons.

The ListView items is as follows (activity_websites):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/locationList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The button xmlfile is as follows (delete.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteBtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:onClick="onClickDelete"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also i have a feeling what i am doing right now is wrong in general to get the view that i want for my app. Can i get some help on these?

Answer (score 0):

The layout you are trying to inflate is `list_item.xml`. From your question I understand that the button is in `delete.xml`. So `convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);` return `null`.

You need to put the `Button` in `list_item.xml`.

Also remove the `android:onClick="onClickDelete"` in the xml. You already have an `onClick` in the adapter.